Camera glitches when displaying UI text (Item Name) for the first time
I have this very specific and wierd bug in my game that when I hover over a item in game and it should display its name it immediately change position of my camera to a random new angle. It always happens only the first time of running the game, so every time after this it works just fine. I dont have any function in my code for camera which should be doing this.
Could someone please help me?
Thanks a lot :)
My Text displaying code is here
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
 
public class SelectionManager : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public static SelectionManager Instance {get; set;}
    public GameObject interaction_Info_UI;
    TextMeshProUGUI interaction_text;
    public bool onTarget;
    public GameObject selectedObject;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        interaction_text = interaction_Info_UI.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        onTarget = false;
    }

    
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(Instance != null && Instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
    }


 
    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            var selectionTransform = hit.transform;

            InteractableObject interactable = selectionTransform.GetComponent<InteractableObject>();
 
            if (interactable && interactable.playerInRange)
            {
                interaction_text.text = interactable.GetItemName();
                interaction_Info_UI.SetActive(true);
                onTarget = true;
                selectedObject = interactable.gameObject;
            }
            else 
            { 
                interaction_Info_UI.SetActive(false);
                onTarget = false;
            }
 
        }
        else
        {
            interaction_Info_UI.SetActive(false);
            onTarget = false;
        }
    }
}

I have already tried reseting the setting of main camera in unity but it didnt solve the issue and I have been looking inside my code for any line which could be moving the camera but it seems its not in code. So maybe its in some kind of setting? I have not found the answer on forum posts or google in general.

Is the camera referenced anywhere else in code? Even as a variable? Please, don't limit your investigation to "any line which could be moving the camera", but what references the Camera itself. You need to understand that Unity can have components (depending on what assets, libraries, modules or packages you use) that can have some sort of automatic behavior that you can't even predict or know about. But since the chances of that are relatively small (depending if you do use some external code - meaning other assemblies not in standard Unity or your code), check for references to it.

The camera is only referenced in Mouse movement script which is very bacis, I can also share it but there is nothing to it expect for very straight foward explanation of how to move camera with mouse

well this code here definitely doesn't move the camera ... so it is probably rather happening in your other script then

I have found out that it was this whole time caused by the raycast.... I googled a lot but I still cannot find the reason for why when I add paramter to 'if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))' and set it like 'if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 5)) then it start glitching my camera for some reason'
